# what does x =!x means?

Tags: c, ghostscript, mupdf

While readinf MuPDF comes across the source code line

```
x = !x;
```

Want to know what does the above code do?

While compilation is also gives error as

```
assuming signed overflow does not occur when simplifying 
condition to constant [-Werror=strict-overflow ]
```

Comment: Are you sure the diagnostic is related to this statement? Can you remove it, compile and then put it back again and compile to confirm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`!x` will evaluate to either `0` or `1`, depending on the value of `x`.

- If `x` is `0`, it evaluates to `1`.
- Otherwise, it evaluates to `0`.

Comment: I don't get that error. The corresponding warning is supposed to be enabled with `-Wall` in gcc and I guess by extension in clang. I don't see the error with the latter. You should post an MCVE that reproduces the error.

Comment: Use flag strict-overflow

Comment: @Vineet1982 I already tried. No error. Why not post the MCVE?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming x is boolean, this sets x false if it is true, and true if it is false.